# Mostrar valores de un dataframe filtrando según valores columna - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero obtener 20 muestras de mi dataframe que cumplan la condición que la columna "activo" tenga un "no" y otras 10 que mi columna "Activo" tenga un "si". He hecho lo siguiente:

```
activo_no = (df['activo'] == 'no').sample(n=10)
activo_si = (df['activo'] != 'no').sample(n=10)
```

Una vez tengo las 20 muestras (10 y 10) querría mostrar un dataframe con estas.

```
sampled = pd.concat([activo_no, activo_si])
print sampled
```

Pero esto solo me muestra número de fila y su booleano en función de si era si o no (muestro mi resultado en la imagen siguiente). Y yo querría que saliera todo, es decir, esas 20 muestras y todas las columnas con sus respectivos valores. Además si nos fijamos he subrayado un valor que se ha colado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A raiz de mis resultado imagino que no está bien hecho y pienso que quizás `groupby` sería mejor, pero no consigo nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que haces con `(df['activo']=="no")` no es seleccionar solo las filas en las que se cumpla esa condición, sino que el resultado es una copia de la columna `'activo'` **completa**, en la que cada valor original se ha sustituido por `True` (si la condición era cierta) o por `False` (si no).

Al hacer `.sample(n=10)` de ese resultado, estás tomando 10 elementos de esa columna, de los cuales algunos pueden ser `True` y otros no. Por tanto no es raro que se te haya "colado" el que has detectado. ¡Lo raro es que solo se haya colado uno!

Lo que quieres es seleccionar del dataframe original (`df`) todas aquellas filas para las cuales haya un `True` en el resultado anterior. Esto es muy sencillo:

```
activo_no = df[df['activo'] == 'no'].sample(n=10)
activo_si = df[df['activo'] != 'no'].sample(n=10)
```

Es decir, el resultado de tu expresión `(df['activo'] == 'no')` se usa como índice en `df[indice]`, y eso produce el resulado deseado. Sólo las filas seleccionadas por la Serie de booleanos que le estás pasando entre corchetes. Además, el resultado es simplemente un sub-conjunto del dataframe original, con las filas que no te interesan eliminadas, pero con todas sus columnas conservadas así como sus valores. No `True`s o `False`s sino los valores. Es decir, lo que buscabas.

Sobre ese resultado ya puedes aplicar `.sample()` para extraer un subconjunto de filas aún menor (10 en este caso).